# The Fastest/Simplest Algorithm/Function to Determine Largest of Three Values

Tags: r, algorithm, conditional-statements, dplyr

A **very** basic programming question here, but for future's sake I just want know which way would be the very best way to handle this common situation.

I have three columns of varying levels between 0 and 10, and I wish to determine which of them has the highest value of all, and display the column's name (in the mutated column or otherwise created 'Largest' column.) In the event of any ties I prefer favoring the c over b over a column, since this switch will be used to pull values from other columns which might not be equivalent like these are.

The code below does the trick, but is there a shorter and simpler way?

```
set.seed(7)
mat <- matrix(as.integer(runif(15, 0, 10)), nrow = 5, ncol = 3)
colnames(mat) <- letters[1:3]
(mat)

matBestOf <- 
    data.frame(mat) %>% 
    mutate(Largest = ifelse(c >= b & c >= a, "c",
                     ifelse(b >= c & b >= a, "b",
                     "a"))
           )
matBestOf
#   a b c Largest
# 1 9 7 1       a
# 2 3 3 2       b
# 3 1 9 7       b
# 4 0 1 0       b
# 5 2 4 4       c
```

I tried using the `max()` function, but I am only getting it to return the highest value instead of the column name with the highest value. Additionally, I am apparently not comparing values out of all three columns as the results are only coming out of the best of *a* and *c*, and never *b*. Additionally, it seems I can not favor the higher letter, which is okay and maybe I can live without that added feature.

```
matBestOf <- 
    data.frame(mat) %>% 
    rowwise %>% 
    mutate(Largest = max(a:c))
matBestOf
# Source: local data frame [5 x 4]
# Groups: <by row>
#
#       a     b     c Largest
#   (int) (int) (int)   (int)
# 1     9     7     1       9
# 2     3     3     2       3
# 3     1     9     7       7
# 4     0     1     0       0
# 5     2     4     4       4
```

Comment: May be this would help you . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10290801/getting-column-name-which-holds-a-max-value-within-a-row-of-a-matrix-holding-a-s

Comment: Your making several unnecessary tests in your solution, you only need 3 comparisons in the code and only 2 of the 3 need to be executed. See example 2 here: http://www.programiz.com/c-programming/examples/largest-number-three

Comment: Excellent! Thank you for feedback and the helpful link: I had looked all over for something just like that.  [Code updated above.]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an option with `max.col`:

```
mat %>% 
  data.frame() %>%
  mutate(Largest = names(.)[max.col(., ties.method = "last")])

#  c b a Largest
#1 1 7 9       a
#2 2 3 3       b
#3 7 9 1       b
#4 0 1 0       b
#5 4 4 2       c
```

I use `select` to put the columns in the order you specified so that we can simply use `ties.method = "first"`. The `everything()` ensures that other columns (if present), will also be selected, but appear after the first three columns.

Comment: @leerssej mat needs to be converted to data.frame, see edit.

Comment: 2 new functions: everything(), and max.col(), and relearned how I should transform an index into its related value. Thank you!

Comment: @leerssej, welcome! Btw, in your case (c over b over a) you could also leave out the `select` statement and change `ties.method = "last"`.

Comment: @docendodiscimus updated your post with `last`, hope you don't mind, it give 0.3mins better performance :) on `bigmat` data.

Comment: @zx8754, no problem, thanks for updating and benchmarking

Answer (score 3):

Using `apply`, and `rev` to give priority to c over b over a:

```
cbind.data.frame(mat,
      Largest = apply(mat, 1,
                      function(i)rev(colnames(mat))[rev(i) == max(i)][1]))
#   a b c Largest
# 1 9 7 1       a
# 2 3 3 2       b
# 3 1 9 7       b
# 4 0 1 0       b
# 5 2 4 4       c
```

**Edit:** Benchmarking

Taking rev outside apply makes the code 3-4 times faster on a bigger data, still not as fast as `dplyr` solution.

```
library(dplyr)

# bigger dummy data
bigmat <- matrix(rep(mat, 10000), ncol = 20)
colnames(bigmat) <- letters[1:ncol(bigmat)]


microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  dplyr = {bigmat %>% 
      data.frame() %>% 
      select(c,b,a, everything()) %>%
      mutate(Largest = names(.)[max.col(., ties.method = "first")])},
  base_apply_v1 = {
    cbind.data.frame(bigmat,
                     Largest = apply(bigmat, 1,
                                     function(i)rev(colnames(bigmat))[rev(i) == max(i)][1]))
  },
  base_apply_v2 = {
    myFlip <- bigmat[nrow(bigmat):1, ncol(bigmat):1]
    myNames <- colnames(myFlip)
    cbind.data.frame(bigmat,
                     Largest = apply(myFlip, 1,
                                     function(i)myNames[i == max(i)][1]))
  }
  )

# Unit: milliseconds
#           expr       min       lq      mean    median        uq        max neval cld
#          dplyr  3.271673  3.52583  4.665696  3.730951  5.915583   8.405259   100 a  
#  base_apply_v1 86.191320 91.94412 99.370839 93.709812 96.214598 196.007909   100   c
#  base_apply_v2 23.121803 26.70536 30.906054 28.042854 29.065466 134.257780   100  b
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an option using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
as.data.table(mat)[, Largest := rev(colnames(mat))[which.max(rev(unlist(.SD)))] , 1:nrow(mat)][]
#    a b c Largest
#1: 9 7 1       a
#2: 3 3 2       b
#3: 1 9 7       b
#4: 0 1 0       b
#5: 2 4 4       c
```